# How to save log in session and other cookies to access a website some time later?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, session-cookies

I know we can enable cookies in scrapy setting to navigate to different pages of a website without re-log-in every time once we successfully log in to that website. But, this is limited to a single execution or run of a spider. So, my concern is can we save those cookies in a file or in a database and use that later whenever we want to access to the website unless the session expires? Thanks.

Comment: There’s no built-in feature for that in Scrapy, but it should be fairly easy for you to implement such behavior in your spider.

Comment: Hi @Gallaecio, what I tried was parse response headers, save headers and cookies in a json file and reuse the headers in `scrapy.Request()` method as headers argument. But this didn't work well. What would be your approach? Can you please guide me through that?

Comment: You should only need to save the cookies, not the response headers. Other than that, it sounds like what I would have done. Do the cookies work if used right away in a new request (no file saving and loading)? Have you checked if the response indicates the type of issue? (e.g. expired session)